# How to remove different color spaces near next and previous buttons in buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

The code I'm using for previous and next buttons in carousel is as follows:
[COde screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU1rA.jpg)
But I'm having a problem of different background color near those button as shown in the screenshot I've attached:

[image]<\a>

Could anyone please me removing those grey background. Please let me know the alternatives I can use also.

Comment: Post your code in your question, where it should be, rather than a screenshot of your code that can't be copied, or searched, easily to reproduce your problem. Please see the "[mcve]", and "[ask]", guidelines for reference.

Comment: No, please [edit] your question and, once your question no longer deserves the down vote, or the vote-to-close, then I'll remove the down-vote, and close-vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the carousel left and right classes background images to none! Your problem will be solved!

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `background-image` property to none.

```
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none!important;
}
```

Comment: @amit: please edit your question to include your full question, don't drop-feed your question in comments.